# Why it is impossible to type location in Ubuntu's "Time & Date" in Cyrillic script?

Tags: time, timezone, location, places

Why is it impossible to type (or find) the Russian city's name (e.g.: Moscow, Yekaterinburg) in `All Settings > Time & Date > Clock > Choose Locations` of Ubuntu 14.04.5 using Cyrillic script *(кириллица)* *(Москва, Екатеринбург)*, while there is – simultaneously - no problem with finding Shanghai (City) or Hong Kong, using *hànzì (汉字)* *(上海市, 香港)*, even without Chinese language support installed?

I have proper input sources (keyboard layouts) installed, but *Екатеринбург* is not on the list, only: *Yekaterinburg*. To find New York City though (not Chinese, yet), you can simply enter *纽约*. Why is *Нью-Йорк* not treated equally?

Comment: As far as I know, Ubuntu uses GeoNames, which [supports Cyrillic as of at least 2006](https://geonames.wordpress.com/2006/08/21/cyrillic-place-names/) (e.g. [search for Москва](http://geonames.org/search.html?q=Москва)). So I'm guessing this is a bug.

Comment: @wjandrea: As noted above: _Москва_ does not work, but _莫斯科 (Mòsīkē; Moscow in Mandarin)_ does. Is it possible to eliminate the alleged error? To reinstall "Time & Date" utility?

Comment: If it's a bug like I think, there's nothing you could do except report a bug against the package: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center